# Bootstrap: set inline elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, inline

I need to align perfectly several elements included in a `<div>`.
These elements are a `<span>`, a `<h4>`, a `<img>` and a `<a>`. I'm using Bootstrap3. You can directly see the code on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wiltomap/pqrsb995/).

Here my HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="data-head">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-random"></span>
    <h4>Network length</h4>
    <img src="http://www.jotform.com/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>
    <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

h4 {
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.data-head {
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

I have tried many thnigs such as `display:inline-block` or the Bootstrap classes `inline` but I can't manage to achieve this and I'm getting a little bit lost within the possible solutions... I thanks you greatly in advance for help and advice!

Comment: What should the order of the elements be?

Comment: You can make h4, `display:inline-block`. Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pqrsb995/2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify your css as follows:

```
.data-head {
    padding: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and then you have to provide "float:left" to each element i.e. to `span`, `img`, `h4`, `a` add `margin-top: 0px;` to `h4`

Answer (score 0):

Although, they're all not "perfectly" aligned please see the following updated fiddle which should help you: http://jsfiddle.net/nyy6w5ew/3/

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div id="ass" class="col-md-12">
    <div class="data-head">

      <div class="data-title">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-random symbols"></span>
        <h4>Network length</h4>
        <div class="inner">
          <img src="http://www.jotform.com/images/ajax-loader.gif" id="loading-ass" class="loading loading-ass" />
          <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down show-data" id="ass-lineaire"></a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Also added the following **CSS:**

```
.data-title span, .data-title h4, .data-title .inner img, .data-title .inner, .data-title .inner a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I've given the div that didn't have a class (within `.data-title`) a class of `.inner` and also gave that a `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with "float: left"

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
body {
  margin: 20px;
}

h4 {
  margin-left: 35px;
  display: inline;
}

.data-head {
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```